# Flutter работа Consumer с map

Tags: flutter

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Мне нужно List сделать в Map = {id : quantity}. Как мне с помощь Consumer пройтись по Map?

Код корзины

```
Stack( 
    children: [
      Consumer<Cart>(
        builder: (context, value, child) => value.items.isNotEmpty
            ? ListView.builder(
          itemCount: value.items.length,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
              CartPageItemTile(value.items[index]),
        )
            : Center(
          child: Text('Корзина пуста'),
        ),
      ),
      Breadcrumb(),
    ],
  )
);
```

Код модели корзины

```
class Cart extends ChangeNotifier {

  List<int> _cartItems = [];

  List<int> get items => _cartItems;

  void add(int itemNo) {
   _cartItems.add(itemNo);
   notifyListeners();
 }
 void remove(int itemNo) {
  _cartItems.remove(itemNo);
  notifyListeners();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List list = [];
list.add(Customer(10, 2));
Map<int, int> map1 = Map.fromIterable(list, key: (e) => e.id, value: (e) => e.quantity);
map1.forEach((a, b) {} );
```